# Commercial Mapping software - South Africa

Tags: mapping, gis

I am looking for a good quality and reliable mapping solution for South Africa.

We require similar functionality to Bing and Google. ie plotting markers on the map, geocoding, drawing polygons, popups on the map showing content etc.

So far Google maps looks like the winner, but are there other options that you would recommend.

thanks

Comment: In what way is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best options thus for are http://www.openstreetmap.org/ or Google Maps. Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

The Maptitude [Mapping Software](http://www.caliper.com) is used in South Africa, see: caliper.com/Maptitude/SouthAfrica.htm, and allows you to interact with data from a variety of sources including Google and OpenStreetMap.

Disclaimer: I may receive some form of compensation, financial or otherwise, from my recommendation or link.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the folks that run [linfinity](http://linfiniti.com/) have done lots of work in Africa. they'll be glad to help you

Comment: Thanks, I will give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

I came across PlanetGIS today by chance. It looks like they may be a good source of data which could be used on top of a Google Maps solution (I'd recommend OpenLayers personally though).

http://www.planetgis.co.za/data.php